# How to transpose a matrix in Ocaml

Tags: algorithm, match, ocaml, transpose

I am trying to transpose a matrix using pattern matching in Ocaml, I can't use any modules or map function, any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your matrix representation is a list of lists. In many cases the best representation would be an array of arrays or a two-dimensional bigarray, but these don't offer any real opportunity to do pattern matching.

So, say `m` is a list of lists. The first list of the transpose will be the list of first elements of all the lists in m. You might start by writing a function that takes a list of lists and returns a list consisting of the first elements of each of the lists:

```
first_elems [[1; 2]; [3; 4]] =>  [1; 3]
```

To make the recursion work nicely you might need another similar function that returns all the elements other than the first:

```
rest_elems [[1; 2]; [3; 4]] => [[2]; [4]]
```

Note that if you apply `first_elems` to this result you get the second list of the transpose.

If you can write these (somewhat) simpler functions, you can probably combine them to produce the whole transpose.